# Instalación de "tidyverse" en R teniendo GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, r

Cuando corro `install.packages("tidyverse")` me sale el siguiente mensaje:

````
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'``` .
````

Obviamente que no estaría acá si no hubiera probado `sudo apt install libcur14-openssl-dev` ya que me da el siguiente error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcur14-openssl-dev
```

Ya no sé que más hacer y no le encuentro solución al problema.

Comment: Bienvenido Ezequiel Figueroa a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que sabor de Linux tienes?

Comment: Como estás usando `apt` asumo que usas Ubuntu o Debian. En Ubuntu 18.10 está en repo oficial (me consta, lo instalé), para Debian Jessie lo mismo. A menos que estés usando una distro muy rara o muy nuevísima esa librería debería estar. Prueba con `sudo apt update` para que se actualice el índice de repos.

Comment: Hola! la distro que uso es mint, y suelo semanalmente actualizar los repositorios asi que no creo que sea eso.

Comment: ¿Has probado hacer `sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`?

Comment: Si, probe con libcurl4 y de hecho era una de las librerias que me faltaban. La ultima que agregue que me soluciono el problema fue libz-dev. Gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema pero uso Ubuntu 20.04, alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo? Probé las opciones anteriores y no.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas distribuciones de Linux a veces no son compatibles con las últimas actualizaciones de los paquetes que yacen en el R-cran, cuando direccionas la instalación del paquete desde el repositorio de R-cran, no se entrelazan correctamente, ya sea porque no se ha actualizado el sistema operativo (que es el error más común), o que el paquete necesite la instalación de un paquete complementario.

Mi recomendación, es que descargues el zip de tidyverse en el R-cran y si tienes RStudio, instales el paquete utilizando:

1. **tools** y elijes **installpackages**, te aparecerá una ventana.
2. clickea en el botón **Browse** en la parte que dice **Package archive**.
3. y busca la ruta dónde descargaste el paquete en formato **zip**.

El 99% de las veces cuando no puedes instalar por consola, la instalación del paquete de esta manera es infalible.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tampoco me funcionó de ningún modo instalar directamente "**tidyverse**", ya que tuve problemas con algunas dependencias como **googledrive** y **googlesheets4** pero si no las necesitas entonces *puedes instalar las bibliotecas de* "**tidyverse**" de una por una, a mi me funcionó para un trabajo y estas son:

`install.packages("dbplyr")`

`install.packages("ggplot2")`

`install.packages("dplyr")`

`install.packages("stringr")`

`install.packages("purrr")`

`install.packages("readr")`

***Ya que descargaste las bibliotecas puedes llamarlas en tu código:

`library(dbplyr)`
`library(ggplot2)`
`library(dplyr)`
`library(stringr)`
`library(purrr)`
`library(readr)`

En verdad espero esto sea de ayuda